# Restoring tar backup crashes ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, backup, tar

Steps taken to create and restore backup in ubuntu 16.04 :

- **1.CREATING BACKUP**

  - cd /
  - sudo tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz
- **2.Cleaned entire hard disk** for dual booting and then reinstalled ubuntu 16.04.
- **3.Restoring backup on fresh install ubuntu**

  - Moving backup.tar.gz from external drive to `/` directory
  - cd /
  - sudo tar -xvpzf backup.tar.gz -C /
- *AFTER REBOOTING SYSTEM CRASHES !*

Comment: what error do you get? when does it crash? did yo correct /etc/fstab for the new partitions?

Comment: @ravery After restoring I rebooted and then unable to boot as it gets strucked in black screen .

Comment: EFI or Legacy? Did you make the HDD bootable?

Comment: @ravery I was just making a tar backup of the whole system so that I can get everything back after restoring tar in reinstalled  ubuntu .

Comment: You are restoring the `/etc/fstab` file from your original configuration, and overwriting the `/etc/fstab` from your new install. This is bad. There are other files you shouldn't overwrite, too, but I don't remember which.

Comment: @MohitMalik, see if you get any verbose when alternate to Ctrl-Alt-F1 of Ctrl-Alt-F2 while system tries boot up

Comment: Yes I got a black terminal and I am able to login  but cannot load Graphical Interface !